# Is it possible to have Nautilus show hidden files except for one specific folder?

Tags: nautilus, hidden-files, google-drive

In general, I like to see all the hidden files. So I have used Ctrl+H to have Nautilus show all the hidden files.

But now thanks to this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/1100525/889735) with google drive, I like Nautilus not to show the hidden files in my mapped google drive folder.

Is this possible?

Comment: So to be clear, you want Nautilus to show hidden files in every folder except in the Google Drive folder, right?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. By design, showing or hiding files in Files (nautilus) is a global setting, immediately affecting all windows.

In past times, it was a per-window setting. It probably still works like this in forked versions of nautilus, such as Nemo (Cinnamon desktop) or Caja (Mate desktop) and probably other file managers.

Thus, you may not be able to adapt the file manager itself. Either you may need to move away from it, or change your habits. You may want to learn to work without hidden files shown. It will reduce the clutter. In normal working circumstances, there is not much point of having the hidden files visible all the time. That is also why the feature is there: to have files present in a convenient location and at the same time avoiding to have to see them all the time. You only need to see these occasionally, and then they are just a keypress, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, away.